# Heat equation with source term in $L^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

To simplify, let us work on $Q_T:=[0,T]\times\mathbb{T}^N$ where $\mathbb{T}^N$ is the $N$-th dimensionnal torus.

Consider $(S_n)_n$ a sequence of $L^1(Q_T)$ and $(z_n)_n$ the sequence of solutions to the heat equation $\partial_t z_n - \Delta z_n = S_n$ (with $0$ as initial data).

Is it true that if $(S_n)_n$ is bounded in $L^1(Q_T)$, then $(z_n)_n$ converges (up to a subsequence) a.e. ? If it is not sufficient, does $(S_n)_n$ weakly converging in $L^1(Q_T)$ sufficient ?

I expect some compactness for the operator $S\mapsto z$ but I did not manage to find some reference for the $L^1(Q_T)$ case.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Apparently $S \mapsto z$ is compact by Corollary 5.1 in [S. P. Eveson
Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 123, No. 12 (Dec., 1995), pp. 3709-3716], https://www.jstor.org/stable/2161898

Comment: @ Mateusz: I don't see how this covers the heat equation? It seems to me that Eveson's setting - i.e. kernels $k(x,y)$ with $(x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega$ in a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^N$ - rather corresponds to Green's functions for elliptic problems. Am I missing something?

Comment: If this question ever finds a definite answer: can we extend to measure right-hand sides (with total variation in place of $L^1$ norm)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the input-output operator $S \mapsto z$ is compact with the $L^1$-controls. For the proof see for instance **Theorem 1.2** in

> R. Triggiani, A note on the lack of exact controllability for mild solutions in Banach spaces, SIAM J. Control Optimization, 15 (1977).